# creating a checkbox in a grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to create a grid in mvc which will have the following columns

```
select -- checkbox,
Invoice date,
Invoice Number,
Acct Number,
Amount,
Amount due
```

Users will be able to click on a checkbox under select column for a line of record. I am new to Mvc. How do I write a viewmodel for this? Do I include the first column "select" in the viewmodel? How will I also represent this in my html?

Answer (score 1):

[Information about webgrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx)

Your ViewModel is just a normal model:
Boolean, DateTime, int, int, int, DateTime (I guess). And your select is just plain text; it is not going to vary from record to record.